# CSS flexible boxes & Inner paddings

Tags: html, css

I am trying to only add *inner* paddings/spacing to three columns in a grid floating to each other. So the padding will not be applied to the left of the first column and to the right of the last column.

The illustration below demonstrate what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

For a grid with two columns, I simply did the following:

```
.grid .size-1of2 {
    width: 50%
}
.grid .column.size-1of2:first-of-type {
    padding: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.grid .column.size-1of2:last-of-type {
    padding: 0 0 0 5px;
}
```

And it worked, as the space between the columns what 10px spot-on! However, now when I try to do the same to a grid with 3, 4 and 5 columns. Things just get messy and mathy!

Here is what I have so far for the three columned grid:

```
.grid .size-1of3 {
    width: 33.33333%
}
.grid .column.size-1of3 {
    padding: 0 4px 0 4px;
}
.grid .column.size-1of3:first-of-type {
    padding: 0 7.5px 0 0;
}
.grid .column.size-1of3:last-of-type {
    padding: 0 0 0 8.5px;
}
```

The html is really simple, note: The .column's are generated by the plugin(1) described below:

```
<div class="grid columns3">
   <div class"column size-1of3">
     <div></div>
   </div>
   <div class"column size-1of3">
     <div></div>
   </div>
   <div class"column size-1of3">
     <div></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**The question is:** 
What is the best approach to solve this problem? having *10px* *inner* gab between the columns with maintaining *consistent* columns widths?

I am using this **plugin (1)** to create the grid system http://savvior.org - the plugin purely creates the columns requested and sort the elements inside it equally. So the padding is simply a styling feature which the plugin does not do but I am trying to implement.

**LIVE TEST SITE: http://loai.directory/test-grid**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use [flex-boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) , this is what they're meant for !!

Just set `.grid {display:flex  ; flex-wrap: nowrap}`

and check out the magic flex-box property;

also read documentation for the complete property specs.

Comment: Hmmm, sounds promising but I tried it and nothing happened, am I doing it wrong?

Comment: I have put a live example here: http://loai.directory/test-grid would this be of any good?

Comment: for me it works, you need to take out the padding and add justify-content:space-between; on the grid -- set width of item so you have space left and voila...

Comment: You are correct, it worked. I am only having one problem. I need space between the items. I can't use margin / px right? this is what I am trying to do, I am trying to find a workaround using calc(33.33% - 30px); but no hope. any ideas?

Comment: In the CSS now it show as follows:

*.grid .column {
   margin: 0 5px;
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: top;
 }
 
 .grid .column:first-of-type {
   margin-left: 0;
 }
 
 .grid .column:last-of-type {
   margin-right: 0;
 }*

Comment: setting widths in order to leave some space (ex 30%)?

Comment: Bummer. CSS Flex isn't working on Safari Windows 8 -.- do you think we can have a workaround for it?

Comment: Nice website! I have tried: -webkit-display: flex;  but it does not do anything do I need to do it for the "width: calc(33.33% - 6.5px);" as well?